# Is it possible to figure out which http request generated the corresponding response

Tags: linux, networking, http, tcpip, iptables

I am using iptables to listen to tcp (http) packets. I am filtering out INPUT responses containing a matching string. Is it possible to know which http request generated the response. Assuming 10 requests were sent to the same server and one response containing matching string was generated by one of the 10 requests.
 Is it possible to figure out which request generated the response using iptables, by using markers!

Comment: Do you just mean at a TCP level?  The destination port of the reply matches the source port of the request, so you can at least tie it to the TCP session.  There may be multiple requests within a single session however.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple requests and responses. I want to match all responses corresponding to requests, all requests being sent to the same server

Comment: Did you follow what I meant by source port?

Comment: All the browsers use http pipelining. I suppose all the requests sent by any open tab will use same source port for all the requests. Different tabs in a browser use different source ports.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to fetch the url which generated the request. I can extract the http header, but response headers don't contain urls. If i could know somehow which request generated the response, keeping in mind that a response may not be necessarily preceded by its request, there may be other requests.

Comment: Using ports did the job!

Answer (score 2):

`iptables` is not the right tool for filtering HTTP, because that protocol works on top of TCP/IP (which `iptables` was designed to handle). The problem is, that a HTTP request (or response) may span multiple TCP packets. A proxy (e.g. [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)) is probably a better solution for your problem. Or perhaps [l7-filter](http://l7-filter.clearfoundation.com/).